# Allowing Ping from Mininet to External VM

Tags: mininet, ryu

how do I allow pinging from hosts inside Mininet to External VM using RYU controller.

In terms of pinging, i am able to ping as the following:

1. hosts to hosts
2. hosts to switches
3. RYU controllers / S1-3 Switches to internet
4. RYU controllers / S1-3 Switches to External VM.

Hence, I am looking for solutions on how to allow host (h1-6) to connect to the internet or external vm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzXnv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via configuring VirtualBox (if you are using it). There are more than one way to do it, but take a look at this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/enable-internet-virtualbox/)